# Deploying telegram bot to production along with Django web-site

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Here are my bot.py scripts:

```py
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Start")


def main():
   updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
   dp = updater.dispatcher

   dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

   updater.start_polling()

   updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can run it locally by `python bot.py`
However, I do not know how to deploy to the Django production server.

How to make it work with `view.py`? Do I have to create a view for it?
Can anyone help?

Comment: did you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create and store somewhere `Dispatcher` (have it like a Singleton) and serialize `Update` manually without using built-in Updater. See [example with no threading](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks#alternative-no-threading).

```py
from telegram import Bot, Update
from telegram.ext import Dispatcher

def create_dispatcher(token):
    # Create bot, update queue and dispatcher instances
    bot = Bot(token)
    
    dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, None, workers=0)
    
    ##### Register handlers here #####
    
    return dispatcher


dispatcher = create_dispatcher(TOKEN_HERE)


def webhook_view(request)
    update = Update.de_json(json.loads(request.body.decode()), dispatcher.bot)
    dispatcher.process_update(update)
    return '{"status": "ok"}', 200
```

Also you'll need to [setup Webhooks](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Webhooks) for that

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to include it as a management command and run that command on a schedule (Heroku scheduler is easy if you want to deploy to Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler). Management commands basically execute a function you define with the command `python manage.py your_command_name`. How to write custom management command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: let me try. will post the answer back if succeeded, thanks in advance.